# What happens to the energy in the magnetic field of a ferromagnet when it is heated past its Curie Temperature?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, material-science, ferromagnetism

I know that there is energy associated with magnetic fields given by the formula
$$W=\frac{1}{2\mu_0}\int_{{\rm all\,space}}B^2\,dV.$$
I also know that a ferromagnet like iron is surrounded by a magnetic field (provided it has been magnetized). Now suppose we take a fully magnetized piece of iron so that there is energy associated with the magnetic field surrounding it and call this energy $E_0$. We then heat up the magnet just past its Curie point, so that it suddenly loses its magnetization and hence its surrounding magnetic field. What has happened to the energy $E_0$? It previously existed in the magnetic field but after we crossed the Curie point the field disappeared.

My thinking is that this reaction is somehow exothermic and the energy must be released as heat but I'm not sure how or why. Any help on this issue or some informative sources on this topic would be most appreciated!

Comment: check out the [The magnetocaloric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you take a "proper" second-order ferromagnet-paramagnet phase transition (which happens to be the case for pure iron), then the magnetization does not disappear suddenly. It is a continuous phase transition, hence there are no jumps in magnetization. Moreover, in the presence of an external field the magnetization does not turn to zero even above critical temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction in the magnetic field within the magnet would be accompanied by eddy currents, in accordance with Faraday's law (EMF driving the current is $\varepsilon = -\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Sigma}{\mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{S}}$). These currents would be dissipated as heat through the resistivity of the material.

In principle, energy may also be emitted via electromagnetic radiation. However, this radiation would not be significant if the inverse plasma frequency of the material were much smaller than the timescale of the collapse of the magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did something similar to this in a science project for school, but the magnets did not lose their magnetism immediately rather it took a while. But what does interest me now that I think about it is how the currie effect even works. If heating it up to the currie temperature allows the particles to realign randomly (and thus lose magnetism) why would the particles even realign in the first place? They should keep aligned to the magnetic fields but they don't. I guess I myself have some researching to do.